# How to specify types for intermediate variables explicitly?

Tags: haskell

I have a function `readConfigFromEnv` that reads some env var from the environment variable.

```
readConfigFromEnv :: IO (Int, String)
readConfigFromEnv = do
  portStr <- getEnv "PORT"
  let port = read portStr
  secret <- getEnv "SECRET"
  return (port, secret)
```

Even though Haskell has awesome type inference system, I still want to explicitly specify the types that I expected, and let the compiler tell me if there is anything doesn't make sense:

```
readConfigFromEnv :: IO (Int, String)
readConfigFromEnv = do
  portStr :: String <- getEnv "PORT"
  let port :: Int = read portStr
  secret :: String <- getEnv "SECRET"
  return (port, secret)
```

But this code doesn't compile. However, the compiler hints that I should add the language extension `ScopedTypeVariables`. I tried it works.

So my questions are:

1. Is adding `ScopedTypeVariables` the right way to explicitly specify types for intermediate values?
2. Is explicitly specifying types a good practice?
3. Is there any side effect of using `ScopedTypeVariables`, should I add this to my default language extension list?

Thanks!

Comment: Two comments to add: use `readIO` instead of `read` to force a crash immediately on malformed input, instead of some tricky-to-pinpoint later time when the `port` is first actually used; and you can always just move the type signature to the other side, as in `let port = read portStr :: Int` (or `port <- readIO portStr :: IO Int`).

Comment: Thanks @DanielWagner. The thing is in some case my Monad was a type class rather than a concreate type, I can put the type signature in the other side. For example, if I was using MonadIO or ReaderT where I only know the Monad will return me a String, but I won’t know what exactly the Monad it is.

Answer (score 5):

Without `ScopedTypeVariables` you *can* add type signatures for variables introduced in blocks of declarations, like `let` statements in do-blocks, `let ... in ...` expressions, and `where` clauses. The syntax you guessed in your example isn't quite right though, you need to add a separate type declaration outisde the definition of the variable (exactly the same as the way you wrote `readConfigFromEnv :: IO (Int, String)` on a separate line from its definition, rather than writing both at once as `readConfigFromEnv :: IO (Int, String) = do`). So you can, for example, write:

```
readConfigFromEnv :: IO (Int, String)
readConfigFromEnv = do
  portStr <- getEnv "PORT"
  let port :: Int
      port = read portStr
  secret <- getEnv "SECRET"
  return (port, secret)
```

`ScopedTypeVariables` allows you to add type annotations in contexts where you otherwise couldn't, which helps you declare the type of variables introduced in other ways than these "declaration blocks", such as `<-` bindings in do blocks, lambda-bound variables, and variables introduced in `case` patterns.

However the primary purpose of `ScopedTypeVariables` is to allow type variables to have scopes over multiple type annotations; normally variables in two different type annotations are assumed to be different variables even if they have the same name, and so there are a lot of types that are impossible to write without it. Basically with `ScopedTypeVariables` on any variable introduced with an explicit `forall` becomes a definition of a variable, so any use of that type variable name within its scope is actually a reference to this outer-scope variable rather than a new variable. For example, consider this code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

readTwoThings :: forall a. Read a => IO (a, a)
readTwoThings = do
  sx <- readLn
  sy <- readLn
  let x, y :: a
      x = read sx
      y = read sy
  pure (x, y)
```

Here, the type expression `x, y :: a` says that `x` and `y` are of *the* type `a` that appears in the type signature for `readTwoThings`.

Compare what happens when you remove the `forall a.`, and/or swap out `ScopedTypeVariables` for `ExplicitForAll`. In that case you get an error because the `a` that is the type of `x` and `y` is a different variable to the `a` in the type of `readTwoThings`.

In practice I find that the `ScopedTypeVariables` behaviour is usually what you actually want to happen, but because you can find examples like this where the same code means two different things depending on whether `ScopedTypeVariables` is enabled (you might even be able to construct examples where the code compiles either way and does different things!), you can't just blindly turn it on without understanding how it affects type signatures.

---

Now, with all of that background established, here's my explicit answers to your list of questions:

1. Yes if you want to declare the type of *every* local variable where it is declared, you'll need `ScopedTypeVariables`.
2. Explicitly specifying the types of every top level definition is a very common recommendation, I'd say it's nearly consensus among the Haskell community. I also find it helpful to add type declarations to `let` and `where` bound variables if they're at all complicated, but that practice is less widespread. Adding types to things like `portStr <- getEnv "PORT"` isn't common at all, but it's a matter of taste really. I am pretty sure I would find the extra effort to write the code and hindrance changing it to be more annoying than the benefit.

   I can see why you would want to do this in really large function definitions (especially very long do blocks), but I would generally try to split those up into smaller pieces (either top-level or with `where` clauses), and the pieces would have type declarations.

   So my vote would be no it isn't good practice, but this is a subjective opinion, not an objective fact. Don't let it stop you trying it if it seems like it would be helpful to you.
3. See all of the discussion above. `ScopedTypeVaribles` is a great extension; a lot of people would be perfectly comfortable switching it on by default, and many would even like it to be part of the base language one day. There is absolutely no drawback about turning it on, apart from confusion if you don't know what it actually does.

Comment: One more thing to add, you can specify the type of, for instance `portStr` in `portStr <- getEnv "PORT"` indirectly by specifying the type of the whole expression, that is `postStr <- getEnv "PORT" :: IO String` (and replace IO with the appropriate monad of the the `do` block for other cases, you might still need `ScopeTypeVariables` if the `do` block is polymorphic in the monad type). This is useful for example in expressions like `x <- readLn` where the type of `x` may remain ambiguous without a type declaration (somewhere), to fix that we can add `x <- readLn :: IO Integer`, for example.

Comment: Note: The ambiguity in the last example of my comment above can also be resolved with `TypeApplications`, that is `x <- readLn @Integer`. However `TypeApplications` aren't always applicable.